# Apocalypse To-Do List

Tags: weapons, apocalypse, survival, food, zombies

Note : I've read some questions dealing with post-apocalyptic scenarios ( [fuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38402/manufacturing-of-fuel-post-apocalypse) and [what next after apocalypse?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/so-weve-survived-the-apocalypse-whats-next) ) and [one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32912/most-effective-strategy-for-surviving-the-zombie-apocalypse) on a apocalyptic situation, but I'm more interested in what to do immediately **while** there is a zombie Apocalypse going on. I don't want Bob spending his entire life at sea or anything.

**Background :** A zombie apocalypse has just happened, due to the military and their scientists - but there are already a lot of zombies. Bob and 3 friends (they're all about 20-23 years of age and unmarried) are all zombie fanatics and have made all sorts of plans on what to do when there is a zombie Apocalypse.
(Also, this is taking place in a average town in America.) So while they do panic, they manage to calm down and think of what to do.

**People :** Bob and his friends are average white males, who have played pretty much every zombie game and have made sure to memorize where the nearest gas-station, market, gun store etc is. They like sports (though zombie games is #1), and Bob likes working out. Let's ignore their family for this question.

**Zombies :** Most of them are the shambling type, though a few (like 3 out of 10) are the running type.

**Question :** What is the best plan of action for Bob and his friends ? Lets say that everyone was at Bob's house watching a zombie movie, and Bob has fully fuelled minivan and some baseball bats.

The plan of action should answer questions like these -

- 1) *What **ranged** weapons are the best ?* A [answer for short-ranged ones](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17194/most-effective-long-term-zombie-killing-weapon/17195#17195) has already been given, but even zombie fanatics don't stock up on maces. And baseball bats against a mob of zombies is slightly ineffective. Should they go for rifles or shotguns ? Or should they use pistols ?
- 2) *Where should they go **first** ?* Pretty much every zombie-plan includes going to the gun-store, and it will be hard raiding a shop with others people trying to grab whatever they can.
- 3) *Where should they camp ?* Holing up in a place with other people will be troublesome (especially if they're panicking and ready to shoot others if they think someone is infected)
- 4) *What food should they get ?* Bob has some canned food, but between the 4 of them, it will run out quickly. Where should he go to loot for food, and what should he take.
- 5) *How should they deal with other people ?* It's conceivable that someone may beg to join them, only to later betray them or leave them as bait. Or if someone joins them, but has been bitten (and is hiding it).

Also, is it possible for them to have some sort of makeshift armour that protects against zombie bites ? That is, it covers arms and legs.

Comment: Just to check, are the zombies the typica super-strength? or just normal human strength?

Comment: You also say they like sports, so do I but im the least fit person you will ever meet, what is their physical condition?

Comment: @Mr.Burns - no maybe slightly more but otherwise normal. Bob's friends liking sports means they participate in sports (lets go with tennis) not just watching it

Comment: @KingofSnakes See the edit to my answer

Comment: If they are such fanatics, they would have seen it coming first and would have prepared in advance (before anyone else).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's obviously too broad - it's broad enough that it's already had a book written on it (Zombie survival guide). A question that requires a book to answer is too broad for SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The answer predates Stack Exchange

No, not kidding... there is an entire book: [The Zombie Survival Guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Zombie_Survival_Guide)

EDIT: From the book's Amazon page:

> The Zombie Survival Guide is your key to survival against the hordes of undead who may be stalking you right now. Fully illustrated and exhaustively comprehensive, this book covers everything you need to know, including how to understand zombie physiology and behavior, the most effective defense tactics and weaponry, ways to outfit your home for a long siege, and how to survive and adapt in any territory or terrain.
>
> Top 10 Lessons for Surviving a Zombie Attack
>
> 1. Organize before they rise!
> 2. They feel no fear, why should you?
> 3. Use your head: cut off theirs.
> 4. Blades don’t need reloading.
> 5. Ideal protection = tight clothes, short hair.
> 6. Get up the staircase, then destroy it.
> 7. Get out of the car, get onto the bike.
> 8. Keep moving, keep low, keep quiet, keep alert!
> 9. No place is safe, only safer.
> 10. The zombie may be gone, but the threat lives on.
>
> Don’t be carefree and foolish with your most precious asset—life.

Comment: Haha, I forgot about that book. Nice find

Comment: lol thats a good one, though I prefer a answer instead of a link.

Comment: @KingofSnakes Well "lol" to you too... I am not going to re-write the book for you just because you want it served on a platter. Now tell me straight: are you looking for the information and genuinely care about it? Or are you just looking for a cheap and lazy way out of doing any actual **work** when researching for your story/game/roleplaying setting?

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors This has nothing to do with game, Im just curious as to what is the best strategy. Just providing a link isn't really a answer, no need to get mad

Comment: @KingofSnakes "Im just curious as to what is the **best strategy**". Then go buy the book. I'm 100% serious here: if you are entirely honest with what I just quoted, and you have a guy that has written an entire **book** on the subject, why would you ever rely on what some people on SE throw together in a few minutes? As far as I can make out it is about 10 - 12 USD in paperback. The least you can do is visit the book's website. Sorry for coming off as cranky but it irks me greatly when questioners expect others to do **all** the effort so the questioner can be spoon-fed by SE.

Comment: @KingofSnakes Also: any question of the sort "What is **the best** to do in this very vaguely and imprecisely described situation?" can only, ever, get an "It depends..." as an answer. There are so many unknown factors involved here so there is no "best" solution to things. And it does not become any less irksome when the question is of the sort "...oh, and please make the answer very comrehensive, covering many different topics, lolkkthxbai!".

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors , You do have a point, the best option for the OP would be to get the book, I agree with that fully. Mine and decom70s answer will be missing certain points and situations as it was thrown together on the fly. The OP however has given quite a detailed question, points 1 and 5 I feel shouldnt have been asked as its is purely opinion based but we can still give an answer on what to do when the zombigeddon happens

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors In that case, I apologise for framing the question in that way. I've read other tactics, but they are more like "you should not do this". And explain why the most popular strategies are wrong. For me, Im interested in those 5 points SPECIFICALLY. Thats why I prefer getting a answer to those 5 pts instead of reading another set of tactics.

Comment: @KingofSnakes Those 5 points are not very specific... those are five **BIG** points! You could write a book about **each** on the topics of weapons, food, living/fortifying and interaction with others. And they all come down to "It depends..." anyway. I mean... the issue of food in survival / prepper situations alone is **huge**. There must be hundreds of books and thousands of webpages covering that. And you think we can squeeze it in among 4 other topics on a SE answer? ->

Comment: @KingofSnakes My advice to you is 1) be more specific... make up some parameters that narrow down the setting you are talking about. Otherwise the only answer you will ever get is "It depends..". Narrow it down, a lot. 2) break it up into single-topic questions. Do not try to get many things into one post. Make it a series. Make it your thing on SE WB.. "King of Snakes's Zombie Survival Series". :) Sorry for being crouchy. I just needed to get the point across. Welcome to SE Worldbuilding, and hope to see you soon with your improved questions. :)

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Thanks, I'll do that. Why not answer my latest question? ;)

Comment: See [Are answers solely referencing novels/movies/etc. okay?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1731/29)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Questioner is asking a question that **needs** an entire book to answer. I have expanded on the answer to include the main points of the book. And I have informed him how he can make better questions that do not require entire books to answer.

Comment: I highly recommend this book (The Zombie Survival Guide).  A few weeks after reading it, I was on a 15-hour drive.  Normally, I would get pretty bored, but this trip I spent the entire time fantasizing about how I would survive the apocalypse.

Answer (score 4):

1) If it comes to weapons, against single zombies or small groups long meelee weapons are quite a good choice. With that I mean things like longswords or Nodachis. The Zombies are propably unarmored, and as you said, few of them actually run, making these weapons extremely powerful against them, because you can usually slice of parts of their body with a strong hit. Additionally, they don't run out of ammo, like guns would do. So if your survivors could find them, take them. If it comes to guns, i'd say shotguns and pistols. Shotguns for crowd control and those pesky runners(hard to aim at them?),
and pistols for single targets or targets on a longer range. Why pistols, not things like rifles? Pistols are smaller, weigh less, the bullets are usually smaller, which also makes them weigh less, they are easier to hide,  and Pistols are more common then Rifles ^^.

2) Get out of the damn town. Nothing is more stupid then scavenging a town with a lot of zombies and scared people. Get out of town, and search nearby villages for supplies, mainly camping equipment and food/water. Smaller Villages=less humans=less Zombies.

3) Where they should camp? Away from civilization, in the woods for example. Zombies will be where humans are, aka towns, citys, etc. And if they got some equipment out of the towns, as i said earlier, they can survive out there for a while.

4) Where to go to loot food? See 2). What food? Anything that doesn't spoil quickly. Meat, fish, etc. is also a good idea, but preserve it by using salt. Cornflakes are also quite good. They don't give you a loot nutrition, but hey, they keep you going. Also, book stores. Book stores can have valuable books, for example you could find a book about Plants. Knowing what you can eat and what not in, for example a forest, can save your life and stop you from starving.

5) Having friends is better than foes. But you should always keep an eye out on the people that you give your trust. And of course, you shouldnt be a dick to them. The more of a dick you are, the higher the chance that they betray you. Generally, real life encounters in such a scenario will be different then say, in a game like DayZ. You might be much more hesitant to pull the trigger on someone you see.

Well, this was my opinion on how to survive the Apocalypse. Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Michael Karnerfors answer is just perfect but I will give a brief(lol) run down on what to do during *zombigeddon*

### tl;dr

Summary of below, stay home, get canned everything as it lasts longer, if you need to leave, go to places that are high up as zombies will struggle to get to you, and it's probably best to trust no one.

**Places to go**

- Home : Home is generally ok, if you live in a house then block the windows with stuff and barricade the door. Have 1 or 2 people on look out and have shift patterns so you can have as much up time as possible
- Flat : A flat is also alright but not as good as a house as many people live there, higher chance of infection, but you only have 1 entrance which can be barricaded so that you can then rappel down the side of the flat to get resources, while preventing other people/zombies from entering by the door.
- Country Side : Country side has its ups and downs (But would be my preferred choice), if you are far enough away you will meet only a hand full of zombies (which means less chance of getting infected) but you are far away from any resources

However, since they are all at Bobs place, lets just remain at home and fortify that place.

**Ranged weapons**

A shotgun is easy to aim and even if it misses the pellets would spread so some damaged would be caused. However, most zombies in the area will notice the sound and will come for you.

A fully automatic weapon, this would be great for dealing with large amounts of zombies, but if only head shots will kill them then at best you will only piss them off and slow them down slightly

A semi automatic weapon, one of the better ones for getting head shots as you can aim it and then fire a short burst, down side is you can just hold it and "mow" them down and you cant just press once to hit many of them

A Sniper - What good is killing 1 zombie a mile away? Reloading is likely to be a pain and unless they have lined up for you it will be useless for mind/close range (unless you want to use it as a club)

**Where to go first**

A few options for this one, you can go anywhere you want really but lets stick to basics

Stay home, you have food, zombies are already all over the place so why leave a safe(ish) zone? Make sure the minivan is ready to go just in case something does happen, have a portion of food/weapons/supplies in the minivan as well, if you need to drop everything and go you dont want to quickly nip to the kitchen because you forgot the rice or soup

*Your men are being overly pessimistic (or overly macho) and believe their families are already dead/zombified so they out right ignore them*

A supermarket/some place that sells food, dried and canned food is best but don't forget the fresh fruit and veg (dried fruit and veg is just as good, canned isn't bad if time is pushed), you need the vitamins etc. Fill your 2 of your 4 bags relatively full of food, each person has their own water (1 person carries more so you can replenish where needed), the last person will carry the misc items, tent, rope, additional ammo stuff that isn't out right needed to live (regardless of zombies)

**Where should they camp**

Kind of went over this already but if they need to camp, do it in a barn, sleep at the top then remove the ladder so nothing can get up. If the barns are available then any place that is above 10ft (at lowest head height) so zombies cant just climb up and have a midnight snack

Don't just set up camp in the middle of the woods or in a large empty field, you can get lost in woods and surrounded in a field, they are just bad ideas to sleep in

*Food has already been covered*

**Dealing with other people**

Cold hearted - If you want to be 100% safe, kill them on sight, you don't know them and if they get turned then that is 1 more zombie to deal with.

Suspicious but not trigger happy - Strip search first for any bites/injuries. Have them carry a lot of stuff in turn for protection, after a few months of through investigating if you trust him/her you can then treat them as one of your own

Willing to save but not permanently - You can save a person if they need it, but then after that they are on their own, threaten if needed but you are trying to live not setup a charity

Willing to help all permanently - As long as you don't give anyone lethal weapons at the start and do a through search for bites/injuries then it isn't impossible, you will get a few nut jobs (keep them away from anything important) and dealing with them is hard enough as it is, each person would need to be handled differently so at first contact, don't give them anything that can do serious harm to themselves or others

---

Considering that they are all going to be traumatised within the first few days, hearing bone crunch and snap from a blow you dealt, dealing with something that was once human, hearing its last breaths till it has died will have a huge impact on Bob and his friends, so the best thing to do is to avoid all forms of combat if possible.

Comment: Micheal just provided a link, which doesn't really answer the question. I just want a short, to-the-point answer instead of reading a entire book. THIS is more helpful answer.

Comment: @KingoSnakes , This isnt as short as I wanted it to be, these kinds of questions I have a habit of rambeling on and missing a few points, it is also my personal opinion for some parts so take it witha pinch of salt, also decom70 answer is similar but is quite different in parts to my answer

Comment: There are spelling errors (though its not like I am great in writing) but you can edit them later, still thanks ^_^

Comment: @KingofSnakes , Yea, that wont happen, I have dyslexia so I would need someone else to edit it for me, but you get the general drift of what Im saying in it

Comment: @KingofSnakes "I just want a short, to-the-point answer". Guess who lives the longest in the zombie apocalypse... the one that goes "Lol, I read this short to-the-point thing on Stack Exchange, that's all I need" or the one that researches the subject. :D

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors : Lol, I'll just smack them with a mace. Maybe I should have added, "zombies outside, need someone to answer this quickly, dont have time to read a book" XD

Comment: @KingofSnakes ...to which the answer would be "Well, your best weapons would be X, Y and Z. Do you have any of those at home?" "Uhm... no?". "Oh man, you so screwed..."

Comment: This goes to you both, take it to chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41607/discusion-apocalypse-to-do-list here you go, talk it out, its for stackoverflow but that is because I made a mistake when creating it, still, talk it out

Answer (score -1):

Bob and his friends are zombie-movie fans, so it is believable that they would be properly prepared for the end of the world.  They would know that getting away from mass populations is critical and that the roads are going to be useless.  So along with backpacks full of protean bars, give them...

Four pairs of [bionic boots](http://www.bionicboot.com) and four [pole-arms!](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009QUVCW)

[image: bionic boots] [image]

Also, Bob should own a secluded cabin in the woods, 20-30 miles from town.